# Backbone MVC, without the router?

Tags: backbone.js, javascript

Is there any library that provides just Model, View and Collection base classes, similar to Backbone's, but without all the router/history/sync stuff?

Comment: you can use backbone just fine without the router.

Comment: MVC is a pattern which defines constraints for information flow between application layer. Frameworks for not "provide MVC", your code does ... or more likely: doesn't.

Comment: @StephenThomas yes, but I would like to avoid including unused code in my build

Comment: @tereško "or more likely: doesn't." What does that mean? And you misquoted me, I said Backbone provides three base classes, which I listed by name; not "provides MVC". I think maybe you're showing off a bit?

Comment: @callum, that's fair, but as an FYI the Router implementation in Backbone is only 60 lines of (very readable) code (and that count includes lines with nothing but a closing brace). Minified and gzipped it's only about 650 Bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [Exoskeleton](http://exosjs.com/) by Paul Miller.

Exoskeleton is a faster and leaner Backbone that supports custom builds. Please note that it does not support IE below version 9. If you need to support older browsers, you might want to stick to backbone.

You can just ignore the Router and use the rest of the framework, or if you want to reduce the code footprint to absolute minimum it is not difficult to remove the Router from the code.

Another alternative is [Bamboo](https://github.com/defunctzombie/bamboo) which is a model layer solution similar to Backbone.Model. You can use it with any view/template library eg. [Reactive](https://github.com/component/reactive) or [Ractive](http://www.ractivejs.org/)